# POST value Not work in some page some server

Tags: javascript, php

Form was submitted in script using

```
window.document.form_id.submit();
```

page redirected to action link but cannot get value using `$_post['name']`

But its work in local not work in server

Comment: Welcome to SO! I hope you'll find the site useful. In my experience, learning to use the site also helped me to grow personally as a developer. This is a great start to asking a good question. You have an idea about what you want to achieve and it makes sense intuitively, however it is missing an example of what you've tried together with the output you observed and the desired output. Please consider adding these such that other users can test your code and provide you with code in return that's useful for you.

Comment: where is your code...?? how you expect community to help you...? what you have tried consider adding it....

Answer (score -2):

You can use this to send the form information to the PHP script using JQuery:

`$('<id/class of your form here>').submit();`

Place this Jquery require in your html + your form

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Then in PHP, all you want is:

```
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];
```

Pay attention to `$_POST`, instead of `$_post`